# Nested association in a where clause doesn't produce valid SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have following models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :documents
  has_many :requests
end

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :requests
  belongs_to :user
end

class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :document
  belongs_to :requester, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
end
```

Basically, there are users which can have many documents. Users can request access to documents of other users.

Now I want to get list of requests with specific status which were sent to a user.

This query executed in a method of `User` doesn't work

```
Request.includes(:document)
       .where(status: Request::SOME_STATUS, documents: { user: self })
```

I get error

```
ERROR: column documents.user does not exist
```

It obviously can be fixed by replacing `user: self` with `user_id: id`, but I don't understand why Active Record doesn't work with `user: self`. Is this behavior documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Request` belongs to a document, so this part of your query is not valid in this context: `documents: { user: self }`

From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where):

> In the case of a belongs_to relationship, an association key can be used to specify the model if an ActiveRecord object is used as the value.

What this implies is that for `self` to work, the relationship has to be `belongs_to` so that you could fetch requests that belong to a particular document.

The reason `user: id` works is because the `documents` table happens to have a `user_id` column.